# traversal of boolean AST in Haskell

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree

I am having trouble completing a task where I am to create a function that uses a generalised fold function to evaluate a boolean AST. I will show you some examples to illustrate.

First, an example of what I want, but for an AST that sums integers:

```
data Expr = Val Int | Add Expr Expr deriving Show

folde :: (Int -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> a
folde f g (Val x)   = f x
folde f g (Add x y) = g (folde f g x) (folde f g y)

eval :: Expr -> Int
eval expr = folde (\x -> x) (\x y -> x + y) expr
```

This works fine.

Now for the boolean AST, and the folding function:

```
data Bexp = T | F | And Bexp Bexp | Or Bexp Bexp deriving (Ord, Eq)

foldb :: a -> a -> (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> Bexp -> a
foldb t f a o T         = t
foldb t f a o F         = f 
foldb t f a o (And x y) = a (foldb t f a o x) (foldb t f a o y)  
foldb t f a o (Or x y)  = o (foldb t f a o x) (foldb t f a o y)
```

What I am having trouble with, is creating a function that does the same as the eval function does for the simple AST above, that is, using the foldb function with some lambdas to evaluate whether the `Bexp` expression is either `T` or `F`.

I don't understand why this function doesn't work:

```
evb :: Bexp -> Bool
evb bexp = foldb (\_ -> True) (\_ -> False) (\x y -> x == T && y == T) (\x y -> x == T || y == T) bexp
```

GHCi doesn't even wanna to compile it because of type error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comment out your type annotation for `foldb` and see what GHC infers.

Comment: Also: note the difference between `Expr` and `Bexp`: the former has a single data constructor with type `Int -> Expr`, while the latter has *separate* constructors of type `Bexp` for each possible `Bool` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to use `foldb` to produce a `Bool` at the very end, we need to choose `a = Bool` in its type. So, we are now using

```
foldb :: Bool 
      -> Bool
      -> (Bool -> Bool -> Bool)
      -> (Bool -> Bool -> Bool)
      -> Bexp
      -> Bool
```

Hence, `foldb (\_->True) (\_->False) ...` is wrong since the first two arguments must be booleans, not functions. We need something like `foldb True False ...`.
The next two parameters must be boolean binary operators like `\x y -> x && y`, which can be written as `(&&)` for short.

We finally get:

```
evb :: Bexp -> Bool
evb bexp = foldb True False (&&) (||)
```

Answer (score 3):

The code does't compile for few reasons.

```
-- Observe type signatures.
foldb :: a -> a -> (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> Bexp -> a
evb bexp = foldb (\_ -> True) (\_ -> False) (\x y -> x == T && y == T) (\x y -> x == T || y == T) bexp
```

If `foldb` takes its first argument as a Function `x -> Bool` then from the type signature of `foldb` `a` is of type function but observe this `(\x y -> x == T && y == T)` here you used `a` as `Bexp`, which don't match at all.

`a` = `Bexp` from `(\x y -> x == T && y == T)`

`a` = `x -> Bool` from `(\_ -> True)`

And also the return type of `evb` is `Bool`, but from your argument passing to `foldb` `a` can be 2 things & the compiler is confused to pick the right type.